# How to pass a lambda expression to a C# constructor from an IronPython script?

Tags: c#, scripting, lambda, ironpython

I'm integrating an IronPython scritping engine into my C# raytracer which, so far, has been a breeze even though I'm completely new to Python. There is one particular thing, though, that I need help with. I have a C# class which defines a constructor like this:

```
public CameraAnimation(Action<Camera, float> animation)
```

In C#, I would instantiate this like so:

```
var camAnimation = new CameraAnimation((camera, time) => camera.Position += new Vector(1, 0, 0));
```

I can't quite figure out how to make a similar assignment for the Action object in IronPython, so how would the Python syntax look?

Comment: Would you list some of the *failure* attempts?
I am sure that we can all learn from your *failure*. (http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000576.html)

Comment: Heh, if you insist. My approach to converting C# code to Python was to paste the C# into a .py file and remove stuff until it compiled. This mostly worked but unfortunately distracted me from the rather obvious point that I should just declare a function and pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Don't worry.  I did the same thing. :)

Comment: Current URI for @Sung's link: https://blog.codinghorror.com/fail-early-fail-often/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I interpreted this right, and Action is a generic delegate, the below works (the stubs I used are included).

Python:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("IronPythonDelegates")

import IronPythonDelegates

def camActionPy(camera, time):
  print "Camera: " + str(camera) + ", time: " + str(time)

IronPythonDelegates.CameraAnimation(camActionPy);
```

CSharp:

```
namespace IronPythonDelegates
{
    public class Camera{}

    public class CameraAnimation
    {
    private System.Action<Camera, float> animation;

    public CameraAnimation(System.Action<Camera, float> animation)
    {
        this.animation = animation;
        this.animation(new Camera(), 1.5f);
    }
    }
 }
```

I corrected the above to use System.Action, and it no longer requires explicit reflection.  It's a bit weird though.  For some reason, I could construct a user-created delegate like:

```
explicitTestAction = IronPythonDelegates.TestAction[IronPythonDelegates.Camera, System.Single](camActionPy);
IronPythonDelegates.CameraAnimation(explicitTestAction);
```

but could not do so with System.Action.  E.g. with

```
explicitSystemAction = System.Action[IronPythonDelegates.Camera, System.Single](camActionPy)
IronPythonDelegates.CameraAnimation(explicitSystemAction);
```

explicitSystemAction is null. TestAction was just defined as:

```
public delegate void TestAction<T1, T2>(T1 one, T2 two);
```

But luckily either way it's fine to just do:

```
CameraAnimation(System.Action)
```

or

```
CameraAnimation(TestAction)
```

though for some reason I don't remember that working when I first tried...

Comment: Note, I found System.Action, but unfortunately changing it to use that inexplicably broke the code...  Looking at it now.

Comment: Did you add a reference to System.Core.dll? System.Action<T> is defined in mscorlib but System.Action<T1,T2> is defined in System.Core.

Comment: Yes, I have a reference to System.Core.  As noted, I have it working now.