# (IronPython) Execute PythonFunction from C#

Tags: ironpython

Here's the situation...I want to be able to pass a python lambda into C# method where the evaluation of the lambda should happen. when I pass in the lambda, it turns into an instance of a PythonFunction. I am stuck here as I don't know how to execute this PythonFunction. I see a "**call**" on this class, but I don't know where to get the CodeContext it requires.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to (or can't) use a delegate, the `ObjectOperations` class is a better bet. It is accessible from `engine.ObjectOperations` (where `engine` is your `ScriptEngine` instance).

```
if(engine.ObjectOperations.IsCallable(myfunction))
    engine.ObjectOperations.Invoke(myfunction, args);
```

That said, a strongly-typed delegate (`System.Action` or `System.Func`, or one of your own) is a better option. You can use `engine.ObjectOperations.ConvertTo` to get a delegate if changing the function signature isn't an option.

Answer (score 2):

There's a similar question here:

[How to pass a lambda expression to a C# constructor from an IronPython script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799987/how-to-pass-a-lambda-expression-to-a-c-constructor-from-an-ironpython-script)

The idea was to use a System.Action delegate to accept the python function and then execute that delegate like you would any other.  I'm not 100% sure, but I think it will work with an IronPython lamda as long as your System.Action delegate matches.

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Or System.Func if you need a return type.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out:

```
var target = myfunction.__code__.Target;
result =  target.DynamicInvoke(new object[] {myfunction, argsForFunction})
```

where myfunction is a PythonFunction instance.

Comment: Prefer using engine.ObjectOperations instead of relying on implmentation details.